# How to find out if an item is present in a std::vector?

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

All I want to do is to check whether an element exists in the vector or not, so I can deal with each case.

```
if ( item_present )
   do_this();
else
   do_that();
```

Comment: searching in a vector is very slow since you have to look at every single element of the vector so consider using a map if you're doing a lot of lookups

Comment: @naumcho: If the vector is sorted there's always binary search, as posted below.  This makes it as fast as a map and if you're only storing values (not key/value maps) then it's going to use a lot less memory.

Comment: maps are certainly not the best choice, but using set might be useful. If you need O(1) lookup time, hash_set is the way to go.

Comment: A superb answer present on a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3451045/472647

Comment: If you're going to search multiple times for different numbers, a hash table would be more efficient.

Comment: The answer(s) to this question do not match the title. I strongly suggest to change the title so that people who seek the answers given will find them. It is not the fault of the person who asked the question of course, but now we have this situation... The most upvoted (and accepted) answers find the element anyway (and then check if they found it). So a better title would be "How to find an item in a `std::vector`, if it exists?" Or something like that.

Answer (score 1209, accepted):

You can use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) from `<algorithm>`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
vector<int> vec; 
//can have other data types instead of int but must same datatype as item 
std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), item) != vec.end()
```

This returns an iterator to the first element found. If not present, it returns an iterator to one-past-the-end. With your example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

if ( std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), item) != vec.end() )
   do_this();
else
   do_that();
```

Comment: Using std::count instead ( std::count(...) > 0 ), would it be "faster in theory"?

Comment: Possibly. It depends on how often you search empty vectors.

Comment: I don't see how count() could be faster than find(), since find() stops as soon as one element is found, while count() always has to scan the whole sequence.

Comment: Actually, you'd want to use !vector.empty(). But whatever.

Comment: Don't forget to `#include <algorithm>` or else you might get very strange errors like 'can't find matching function in namespace std'

Comment: a `bool`. It's a drop in replacement (or initialization) of `item_present` in the original question.

Comment: Has it not bothered anyone that despite the STL being "object-oriented", `.find()` is still _not_ a member function of `std::vector`, as you'd expect it should be?  I wonder if this is somehow a consequence of templating.

Comment: @bobobobo: OOP has nothing to do with members vs. non-members. And there is a widespread school of thought that if something does not have to be a member, or when it does not give any advantage when implemented as a member, than it should not be a member; `std::vector<>::find()` would not give any advantage, nor is it needed, therefore, no, it should not be a member. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: I almost posted asking about whether this could be optimized by only calling `vector.end()` once before realizing that, first, if I'm really concerned with speed, I shouldn't be using `find()` on a vector at all, and second, that `vector.end()` being called once instead of twice is hardly any improvement at all.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare due to cache locality a sorted `vector` will often be far quicker to search than a `map` or `set`.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Thirdly, you may find that the `end() call is inlined by the compiler so there's no actual `call` at all but just a raw pointer.

Comment: @phresnel: If it does not give any advantage to make find() a member of std::vector, how on earth current member functions give an advantage by being members of std::vector of std::map ??

Comment: @Gasso: Nobody rated the sanity of the current members being members in this thread. I just presented that by certain school of thoughts, `find` should not be added as a member to `std::vector`; whether existing members make sense or not was not discussed, and indeed the STL is not well designed in many aspects, mainly because the lack of experience (and my post was a response to bobobobo, who implied that members are part of the OOP concept, but they are not)

Comment: @phresnel I would argue that "when it does not give any advantage when implemented as a member" is false for this case. The advantage being a simplified and clearer interface. For example: `mvec.find(key) != mvec.cend()` is preferable to `std::find(mvec.cbegin(), mvec.cend(), key) != mvec.cend()`.

Comment: @bobobobo Referring to the section in "Containers and algorithms" within https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_introduction.html beginning with the words:  "There are two important points to notice about this call to
 reverse."
I think this sheds some light on the thinking of the designers of the STL, although one might still wonder how much this thinking predated the idea of using C++ abstract classes to define interfaces to make the linkage between algorithms and containers more evident.

Comment: @MSN Why do we need != vector.end() at end to check for the element ? Doesnt find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item) itself suffice to find the element

Comment: @bobobobo : The reason why the find() function is not a member of vector is that it is inefficient. When an object of the STL has a member, that means it is a useful, efficient method; it suggests that you should use it. Since find() can not be implemented efficiently for a vector, it is not a member of vector, and the suggestion is that you use a different container if you need to use find() operations. It has nothing to do with the STL being 'badly designed' as suggested in other comments.

Comment: @PascalEngeler: I'd say, It's not so much about whether the operation is efficent or not, but about whether direct access to the internal data structure allows a more efficent implementation of the algrithm than the generic one, which uses iterators.

Comment: @Claudiu in c++ you can use whatever syntax you like, just takes a page of  the ugliest code and [voilà](http://ideone.com/QlCCl7)

Comment: @ap31: that's true, but when I use code like that in production people yell at me :(

Comment: The error message from GCC/GXX for forgetting to `#include` the `<algorithm>` header when using `std::find` has even gotten worse: `error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >&’ to an rvalue of type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >’`

Comment: I have std::vector<std::any> datatype. how to use std::find for vector of any type?

Comment: @bobobobo So many differing programming paradigms all over the place make it difficult for newcomers.

Comment: @swalog std::find does not require that the user searches the entire range. So for the member function to be equal, it would have to be:
```mvec.find(mvec.cbegin(), mvec.cend(), key) != mvec.cend()``` 
which isn't a particularly cleaner interface than the nonmember function.

Comment: @James Mart: it's been a while, but looking at in now, I don't see how that is true, the implied usage being find with a single argument of element type as key, is already aware of its own range, and can stop on first match, if any. Said in a different way, the values you are suggesting should be passed, are already known in the called scope, so you can drop them and make the interface cleaner.

Comment: @swalog I'm just saying if you make the interface cleaner like that, then your member function no longer directly imitates std::find. std find intentionally takes iterators in to allow the user to define a subset of the total range to be searched

Comment: Fair enough. However, the discussion was on the hypothetical overload that implicitly searches the whole range, and as such does not require range specifics. If, and whenever one wished to search on a range (that isn't the whole range), you'd use find, or a member function like what you mentioned.

Comment: This sucks. There should be a std::vector::contains method.

Comment: @SebastianMach I understand, that `std::vector::find()` is not implemented, as it is not better than `std::find()`. The problem is, that a programmer, that upgrades a certain data structure from `std::vector` to `std::multiset` (or `std::set`) then has to walk through the code and update every place, where a `find()` is performed. It would be nice, if the APIs of `std::(multi)set` and `std::vector` would be as similiar as possible.

Comment: This solution does not work for `std::vector<std::shared_ptr...>` and other pimpl expressions. Does anyone know how to make it work??

Comment: The idea of OO comes from Heidegger, and is a concept of how humans perceive the world and organize information. OO design is about structuring code in a way which is easy for humans to understand. As such, container objects (like `vector`) should mimic the concept of containers in the real world.  The fact that I have to say what type of objects a container can hold (the template parameter) doesn't match the real world, where containers can hold anything provided there's enough space. And since finding things in containers is a common thing to do, it should be part of the container interface.

Comment: It's annoying to use one pattern for std::map which does have find, then a more clunky pattern for std::vector because it does not have find.  Consistency between containers would be nice,

Answer (score 139):

As others have said, use the STL [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) or [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) functions. But if you are searching in very large vectors and this impacts performance, you may want to sort your vector and then use the [`binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search), [`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), or [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) algorithms.

Comment: Good answer!
Find is always o(n).
lower_bound is o(log(n)) if used with random-access iterators.

Comment: Sorting is O(nlogn) though, so it's worth only if you're doing more than O(logn) searches.

Comment: @liori True it depends on your usage patterns. If you only need to sort it once, then repeatedly do many searches it can save you.

Comment: @Brian Neal, sorting a large vector is worth if there has to be many element searches on it. Sorting will be O(nlogn) and O(n) will be better if one has to find an element only once :)

Comment: Be wary this may play havoc with your branch prediction.

Comment: Try to use `std::set<>` together with `find()` indeed. Or use `std::map<>` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 60):

If your vector is not ordered, use the approach MSN suggested:

```
if(std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item)!=vector.end()){
      // Found the item
}
```

If your vector is ordered, use binary_search method Brian Neal suggested:

```
if(binary_search(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item)){
     // Found the item
}
```

binary search yields O(log n) worst-case performance, which is way more efficient than the first approach. In order to use binary search, you may use qsort to sort the vector first to guarantee it is ordered.

Comment: Don't you mean `std::sort`?  `qsort` is very inefficient on vectors.... see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308243/trying-to-use-qsort-with-vector

Comment: Binary search will perform better for larger containers, but for small containers a simple linear search is likely to be as fast, or faster.

Comment: @BillT: Wouldn't a decent binary search implementation switch itself to linear search below some threshold number of elements?

Answer (score 53):

Use find from the algorithm header of stl.I've illustrated its use with int type. You can use any type you like as long as you can compare for equality (overload == if you need to for your custom class).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    typedef vector<int> IntContainer;
    typedef IntContainer::iterator IntIterator;

    IntContainer vw;

    //...

    // find 5
    IntIterator i = find(vw.begin(), vw.end(), 5);

    if (i != vw.end()) {
        // found it
    } else {
        // doesn't exist
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depending on the OP's needs, find_if() could also be appropriate. It allows to search using an arbitrary predicate instead of equality.

Comment: Oops, saw your comment too late. The answer I gave also mentions find_if.

Answer (score 29):

In C++11 you can use `any_of`. For example if it is a `vector<string> v;` then:

```
if (any_of(v.begin(), v.end(), bind(equal_to<string>(), _1, item)))
   do_this();
else
   do_that();
```

Alternatively, use a lambda:

```
if (any_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const std::string& elem) { return elem == item; }))
   do_this();
else
   do_that();
```

Comment: `bind1st` and `bind2nd` are [deprecated since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12) and completely removed in C++17. Use `bind` with `placeholders` and/or lambdas instead.

Comment: Why use `std::any_of()` when we have `std::find()`?

Comment: If the purpose is to check for membership only, why use `std::find()` when we have `std::any_of`?

Comment: @einpoklum std::find is only for C++20. Not all projects are using C++20 already. Don't think that's that easy to migrate big professional projects from one version to another. Believe me.

Comment: @Maf: Fair point, I was under the illusion it was older.

Comment: @Maf what do you mean with "find is only for C++20" ? std::find has been part of C++ since forever.

Comment: I'm so sorry einpoklum and @ABaumstumpf, I was wrong. std::find is also part of  C++11. I made a mistake because my C++ compiler allowed me to use it without including <algorithm>

Answer (score 24):

I use something like this...

```
#include <algorithm>


template <typename T> 
const bool Contains( std::vector<T>& Vec, const T& Element ) 
{
    if (std::find(Vec.begin(), Vec.end(), Element) != Vec.end())
        return true;

    return false;
}

if (Contains(vector,item))
   blah
else
   blah
```

...as that way it's actually clear and readable. 
(Obviously you can reuse the template in multiple places).

Comment: and you can make it work for lists or vectors by using 2 typenames

Comment: @ErikAronesty you can get away with 1 template argument if you use `value_type` from the container for the element type. I've added an answer like this.

Comment: You are basically writing : `if true return true else return false`. The method can be one lined in : `return std::find(Vec.begin(), Vec.end(), Element) != Vec.end();`

Answer (score 15):

Here's a function that will work for any Container:

```
template <class Container> 
const bool contains(const Container& container, const typename Container::value_type& element) 
{
    return std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), element) != container.end();
}
```

Note that you can get away with 1 template parameter because you can extract the `value_type` from the Container. You need the `typename` because `Container::value_type` is a [dependent name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

Comment: Note that this is sometimes a bit too broad - it'd work for std::set for example, but give terrible performance compared to the find() member function. I've found it best to add a specialisation for containers with a faster search (set/map, unordered_*)

Comment: Maybe one day they'll finally add this to the stdlib... instead of people having to ask how to reinvent such a tiny wheel over and over again. It's totally viable now that in C++20 we have `ranges`, so that could just be called `Range` rather than `Container`, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: What do you think about @PascalLaferrière 's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58593692/1593077) of deducing the value type?

Answer (score 13):

From C++20, using ranges (`#include <ranges>`)

```
    //SAMPLE DATA
    std::vector<int> vecOfElements = { 2,4,6,8 };

    //DO SOMETHING IF 8 IN VECTOR
    if (std::ranges::find(vecOfElements, 8) != vecOfElements.end())
    {
        std::cout << "DO SOMETHING" << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Bear in mind that, if you're going to be doing a lot of lookups, there are STL containers that are better for that.  I don't know what your application is, but associative containers like std::map may be worth considering.

std::vector is the container of choice unless you have a reason for another, and lookups by value can be such a reason.

Comment: Even with lookups by value the vector can be a good choice, as long as it is sorted and you use binary_search, lower_bound or upper_bound. If the contents of the container changes between lookups, vector is not very good because of the need to sort again.

Answer (score 10):

With boost you can use [`any_of_equal`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/the_boost_algorithm_library/CXX11/any_of.html):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/cxx11/any_of.hpp>

bool item_present = boost::algorithm::any_of_equal(vector, element);
```

Answer (score 10):

In C++23 we finally have the [most obvious solution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/contains):

```
if (std::ranges::contains(vec, item))
   do_this();
else
   do_that();
```

Comment: Yeah - finally. Such a shame that the committee has been so resistant for so long to people suggesting we need just a "has" or "contains" function for containers. std::map only got contains with C++20, and no love for vector.

Answer (score 9):

Use the STL [find](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find.html) function.

Keep in mind that there is also a [find_if](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find_if.html) function, which you can use if your search is more complex, i.e. if you're not just looking for an element, but, for example, want see if there is an element that fulfills a certain condition, for example, a string that starts with "abc". (`find_if` would give you an iterator that points to the first such element).

Answer (score 6):

You can try this code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

// You can use class, struct or primitive data type for Item
struct Item {
    //Some fields
};
typedef std::vector<Item> ItemVector;
typedef ItemVector::iterator ItemIterator;
//...
ItemVector vtItem;
//... (init data for vtItem)
Item itemToFind;
//...

ItemIterator itemItr;
itemItr = std::find(vtItem.begin(), vtItem.end(), itemToFind);
if (itemItr != vtItem.end()) {
    // Item found
    // doThis()
}
else {
    // Item not found
    // doThat()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) function, found in the `std` namespace, ie `std::find`. You pass the `std::find` function the `begin` and `end` iterator from the vector you want to search, along with the element you're looking for and compare the resulting iterator to the end of the vector to see if they match or not.

```
std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item) != vector.end()
```

You're also able to dereference that iterator and use it as normal, like any other iterator.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename T> bool IsInVector(const T & what, const std::vector<T> & vec)
{
    return std::find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),what)!=vec.end();
}
```

Comment: If you want to adapt `std::find()` to be usable with containers, do it generically rather than for just a vector. And maybe call it `find()` or `stdx::find()` or something.

Comment: This function is a less useful wrapper than `std::ranges::contains`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use count too.
It will return the number of items present in a vector.

```
int t=count(vec.begin(),vec.end(),item);
```

Comment: `find` is faster than `count`, because it doesn't keep on counting after the first match.

Answer (score 3):

I've personally used templates of late to handle multiple types of containers at once rather than deal only with vectors. I found a similar example online (can't remember where) so credit goes to whoever I've pilfered this from. This particular pattern seems to handle raw arrays as well.

```
template <typename Container, typename T = typename std::decay<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Container>()))>::type>
bool contains(Container && c, T v)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(c), std::end(c), v) != std::end(c);
}
```

Comment: Please consider separating the value-type-deduction logic into its own trait, e.g. `template <typename Container> struct value_type { ... etc. ... }`

Comment: @einpoklum I'm quite new to template logic and to be honest, I'm barely able to understand how this solution does its magic. Could you possible expand on the {...etc...}?

Answer (score 2):

(C++17 and above):

can use `std::search` also

This is also useful for searching sequence of elements.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Container>
bool search_vector(const Container& vec, const Container& searchvec)
{
    return std::search(vec.begin(), vec.end(), searchvec.begin(), searchvec.end()) != vec.end();
}

int main()
{
     std::vector<int> v = {2,4,6,8};

     //THIS WORKS. SEARCHING ONLY ONE ELEMENT.
     std::vector<int> searchVector1 = {2};
     if(search_vector(v,searchVector1))
         std::cout<<"searchVector1 found"<<std::endl;
     else
         std::cout<<"searchVector1 not found"<<std::endl;

     //THIS WORKS, AS THE ELEMENTS ARE SEQUENTIAL.
     std::vector<int> searchVector2 = {6,8};
     if(search_vector(v,searchVector2))
         std::cout<<"searchVector2 found"<<std::endl;
     else
         std::cout<<"searchVector2 not found"<<std::endl;

     //THIS WILL NOT WORK, AS THE ELEMENTS ARE NOT SEQUENTIAL.
     std::vector<int> searchVector3 = {8,6};
     if(search_vector(v,searchVector3))
         std::cout<<"searchVector3 found"<<std::endl;
     else
         std::cout<<"searchVector3 not found"<<std::endl;
}
```

Also there is flexibility of passing some search algorithms. Refer here.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search

Comment: std::search is for searching for any of _multiple_ values in a range; for a single value, there's no reason to use it.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna find a string in a vector:

```
struct isEqual
{
    isEqual(const std::string& s): m_s(s)
    {}

    bool operator()(OIDV* l)
    {
        return l->oid == m_s;
    }

    std::string m_s;
};

struct OIDV
{
    string oid;
//else
};

VecOidv::iterator itFind = find_if(vecOidv.begin(), vecOidv.end(), isEqual(szTmp));
```

Comment: `std::find` is just fine in this case, no need for the predicate object.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it is using [`std::count`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count).

Example code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void run_vector_contains_example() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int item_to_find = 3;

    int count = std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), item_to_find);

    if (count > 0) {
        // item found in vector
    } else {
        // item not found in vector
    }
}
```

Admittedly, this method might be slower than `std::find` when dealing with large vectors.