# Sorting vector of pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I need to sort a collection of `Element`. Is there any specific advantage of sorting a vector of `Element*` i.e

```
std::vector<Element*> vectRef;
```

to sorting a vector of `Element`.

```
std::vector<Element> vect;
```

assuming I write the comparator accordingly.

`Element` struct is show below:

```
struct Element
{
    Record *elm;        

    Element(Record *rec)
    {
        elm = new Record();
        //...copy from rec
    }
    ~Element()
    {
        delete elm;
    }
};
```

Comment: If you're working with pointers, you'd want to try out ptr_vector of the boost pointer containers. They're a god-send! (I edited the title to 'vector of pointers' since there is no such thing as 'vector of references')

Comment: Something you may find intriguing if you're inquisitive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342957/why-does-vector-not-have-sort-method-as-a-member-function-of-vector-while-list

Answer (score 2):

How expensive is `Element`'s copy constructor?  Does it do a deep copy of the contained `Record` object?  Sorting a `vector<Element>` will require many copies of `Element` objects unless `swap` is overloaded properly.  I'm not sure what the rules are about whether `sort` must use `swap` and if it must use a user's overloaded version of `swap`; http://accu.org/index.php/journals/466 has some information about that.  Sorting `vector<Element*>` will only be copying pointers around, which is likely to be cheaper.  C++0x changes this, assuming `Element` has an efficient move constructor and move assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how copying of `Element`s is done. As you've shown it above, an `Element` contains a pointer to a `Record`, but doesn't define a copy constructor. *If* that's correct, copying `Element` objects should be cheap and quick, so you'd gain little or nothing by storing pointers to `Element`s.

At the same time, I have to point out that doing shallow copies can easily introduce errors. When/if you change `Element` to do deep copying, you might gain a lot more from storing and sorting pointers instead of `Element` objects (but it'll depend on how expensive it is to copy a `Record`).