# C++ collections with built-in remove operations?

Tags: c++, stl

Which standard C++ collections include built in `remove`/`remove_if` operations?

For example, I see that `list` has them:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove_if/

```
list<int> mylist (...);
mylist.remove(42);
```

but `vector` does not, and I have to do `v.erase(remove(etc.etc.etc.))`

Comment: You could always [look at the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) for each of the containers. I gotta ask....why haven't you done this already?

Comment: Chances are the container types reported by a [search of the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=remove) would be a pretty good indicator of which containers have this, and which do not. That list culls down *considerably* if you [search on `remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=remove_if).

Comment: @Jay Bazuzi I saw it in `algorithm' also, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/

Comment: Related topic: [Why does vector not have sort() method as a member function of vector, while list does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342957/why-does-vector-not-have-sort-method-as-a-member-function-of-vector-while-lis)

Comment: I'm looking for a canonical list, and did a Google search, but didn't find one. I can read the docs myself, but I'm not sure if I'll miss any important, subtle details.

Comment: @Dinesh - That's the non-built-in remove, which can be applied anywhere you have iterators.

Comment: If you want a canonical list why not look at the standard? It tells you all of the member functions that need to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container I see a table listing all the operations on all the STL containers, and `remove`/`remove_if` only appear on `forward_list` and `list`.