# How can I check for existence of element in std::vector, in one line?

Tags: c++, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to find an item in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-stdvector)

This is what I'm looking for:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> foo() {
  // to create and return a vector
  return std::vector<int>();
}
void bar() {
  if (foo().has(123)) { // it's not possible now, but how?
    // do something
  }
}
```

In other words, I'm looking for a short and simple syntax to validate the existence of an element in a vector. And I don't want to introduce another temporary variable for this vector. Thanks!

Answer (score 85):

Unsorted vector:

```
if (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(),value)!=v.end())
    ...
```

Sorted vector:

```
if (std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), value)
   ...
```

P.S. may need to include `<algorithm>` header

Comment: +1 for the P.S., I got the above code from various sources but did not know to include the header and hence my code was giving error. Thank You.

Answer (score 19):

```
int elem = 42;
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(elem);
if(std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), elem) != v.end())
{
  //elem exists in the vector
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)

```
vector<int>::iterator it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 123);

if(it==v.end()){

    std::cout<<"Element not found";
}
```

Comment: Surely the if() condition should be != ?