# check if a std::vector contains a certain object?

Tags: c++, vector

Is there something in `<algorithm>` which allows  you to check if a std:: container contains something? Or, a way to make one, for example:

```
if(a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y)
return true;

return false;
```

Can this only be done with `std::map` since it uses keys?

Thanks

Comment: If it contains something specific, or just of it's not empty?

Comment: Which C++ reference are you using? And the header is called `<algorithm>` - note no .h.

Comment: Something specific such as a custom struct.

Comment: if the container contains a custom struct, then you'll need to implement `operator==` to compare them; then `std::find` will work.

Comment: Like answered in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/571394/651937), I think the most elegant is to use [`boost::algorithm::any_of_equal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39729364/651937).

Answer (score 702, accepted):

Checking if `v` contains the element `x`:

```
#include <algorithm>

if(std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), x) != v.end()) {
    /* v contains x */
} else {
    /* v does not contain x */
}
```

Checking if `v` contains elements (is non-empty):

```
if(!v.empty()){
    /* v is non-empty */
} else {
    /* v is empty */
}
```

Comment: what if x is the last element in v?

Comment: David, end() points to one past the last element, so it all works out.

Comment: Does this account for numerical tolerance when trying to determine if a double is in the vector?

Comment: @NicholasHamilton: No, it uses `operator==`. If you need to account for numerical tolerance, use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and supply a suitable predicate.

Comment: Isn’t find exclusive of the last element?

Comment: @DarnocEloc: No.

Comment: june 2015. my mama was alive back then and I was doing my post doc. mann time passed so fast

Answer (score 139):

If searching for an element is important, I'd recommend `std::set` instead of `std::vector`.  Using this:

`std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), x)` runs in O(n) time, but `std::set` has its own `find()` member (ie. `myset.find(x)`) which runs in O(log n) time - that's much more efficient with large numbers of elements

`std::set` also guarantees all the added elements are unique, which saves you from having to do anything like `if not contained then push_back()...`.

Comment: Great!!! I'm writing a lexer. Sets will be much better than vectors. Does `set` have a `count` method like `map`? I also want to be able to get the index of the element in a set.

Comment: Excellent information! Thank you for both answering the straight question and providing an additional solution.

Comment: This is bad advice. If performance is important, profile. There is no guarantee whatsoever that complexity analysis has anything to say about your specific problem.

Comment: It depends on the number of elements. std::set's lookup characteristics work great for conainers with high number of elements at the cost of data locality. You must perform performance analysis (eg. profiling) to decide how high is high enough to switch from a vector data structure to a set data structure.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg I'm a complete novice in profiling and performance, but if a `set` works like a `vector` in a worst case scenario isn't better to use `<set>` just to avoid including `<algorithm>` that afaik adds too much overhead just to use `find()` .I'm talking about unsorted data.

Comment: @Segmentation The O(n) notation is not about worst cases. AFAIK, `set` doesn't work like a `vector` at all. Most `set` implementations use red-black trees, which have a significant overhead. I don't know what you mean by a header adding overhead. Overhead usually refers to runtime overhead. The best use cases of `set` are "I'm feeling lazy and don't want to think about it," and "I need to get this done quickly." If you care about performance, you need to profile. `unordered_set` might be worth trying.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg Maybe the term overhead wasn't the right choice of words. Including `<algorithm>`, a "heavy" header just to use `find()`, as a project gets bigger will probably affect compile times etc. I know that I may be way out of subject here.

Comment: Be aware of the complexity of all other operations on `std::set`s and `std::vector`s. Appending to a vector is O(1) (if not reallocating). Inserting into a set is O(log n). Inserting into an `std::unordered_set` is O(1) and will never reallocate. Suchs oversights is one of the important reasons why profiling is important!

Comment: For compiling times the same thing applies. When this really becomes an issue then know that there are plenty of things you can optimize. Things like multi-core compilation, proper use of forward declarations, proper software design to reduce compilation dependencies, precompiled headers, and, sometimes and if applicable, the use of explicit template instantiations in cpp files.
I like to always create an `fwd_decl.hpp` file in every project that contains all forward declarations of all classes, structs etc and them simply include them in all other header files without a second thought.

Comment: I agree with @AndreasHaferburg: It will give you only a hint. Also the constants could be much worse and can not be foreseen easily without profiling/benchmarking.

Comment: Note that I wrote a performance test of vectors vs. sets, storing enum values and ensuring uniqueness before push_back into the vector. Looping n times for all values of n from 100 to 1 million, vectors were consistently approximately twice as fast as sets. This was on a relatively modern Mac but running inside a Linux docker container. However, they're very fast. 1 million loops required 62 milliseconds for vectors and 137 milliseconds for sets.

Comment: Any claims about `std::set` being fast are in general False. The big-O notation only gives an Upper-bound for when the size goes towards infinite elements. Do you have that many? No. On the other hand it says nothing about any lower terms.
Always benchmark to see how it really performs. And do those benchmarks in the actual code you want to use - microbenchmarks might be optimised completely different.
(There are enough talks showing just how much faster `std::vector` is in most cases. )

Answer (score 15):

See question: [How to find an item in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-stdvector)

You'll also need to ensure you've implemented  a suitable `operator==()` for your object, if the default one isn't sufficient for a "deep" equality test.

Comment: I normally wouldn't implement a custom `operator==()` for my class to just be able to use `std::find()` once or twice. I would only do that if it actually makes sense to add that override to the public interface of your class. Needing to be able to use `std::find()` doesn't justify that. Furthermore, what if you need to do `std::find()` twice but need to compare your objects in a different way? Like on a different property?

Comment: if you are worried to implement the `operator==`, then I would recommend using `std::find_if`, then you could have re-usable predicates for your different criteria cases