# Is there an STL algorithm to find if an element is present in a container based on some tolerance?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

The problem I am trying to solve is a following: I have a container of floating points (vector of double vectors):

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> dv { {0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0} };
```

Then, assume I have a new point (double vector):

```
std::vector<double> v1 {0.0001, 1.0};
```

I want to check if a point **v1** is present in **dv** container based on some tollerance. The distance between two vectors is calculated as Euclidean distance.

I have looked to the relevant questions and answers:

- [How to find if an item is present in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-if-an-item-is-present-in-a-stdvector)
- [check if a std::vector contains a certain object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450860/check-if-a-stdvector-contains-a-certain-object)

and was also trying to use `std::find_if()` without any success, as it accepts only *unary predicate*.

At the moment I came up with a temporary solution. First, I created a generic function to find the Euclidean distance between two vectors:

```
template <typename InputIt1, typename InputIt2>
double EuclideanDistance(InputIt1 beg1, InputIt1 end1, InputIt2 beg2) {
  double val = 0.0;
  while (beg1 != end1) {
    double dist = (*beg1++) - (*beg2++);
    val += dist*dist;
  }
  return val > 0.0? sqrt(val) : 0.0;
}
```

Second, I created `check_if` function to check if an element is presented in a container based on the tolerance (Epsilon):

```
template <typename Container, typename Element>
bool check_if(const Container& c, const Element& el,
              const double Epsilon = 0.001) {
  auto pos = c.begin();
  for (; pos != c.end(); ++pos) {
    if (EuclideanDistance(pos->begin(), pos->end(), el.begin()) < Epsilon) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And then I can use my code in a context like this:

```
// Check if container contains v1 using check_if()
if (check_if(dv, v1)) {
  std::cout << "Using check_if() - Container contains v1\n";
}
```

So my questions are following:

1. Is there in-house an STL algorithm to achieve the same goal? If no, how could I improve my code? For example, I'm not sure how could I use any distance function in `check_in()` instead of `EuclideanDistance()`?
2. I wonder if AshleysBrain suggestion (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451045/3737891) to use `std::set` instead of `std::vector` could make any difference having a container of floating points?

Comment: I would store point in `std::pair<double>` or `std::array<double,2>` - `std::vector` is an overkill for fixed size data, plus you need to validate that  it always has 2 elements

Comment: Use a lambda that captures `Epsilon` and pass that lambda to `find_if`

Comment: Try again with `std::find_if` because I can't see any reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: With lambda, something like: `std::find_if(dv.begin(), dv.end(), [&](const auto&inner) { return EuclideanDistance(inner.begin(), inner.end(), v1.begin()) < Epsilon; })`

Comment: @Jarod42 it cannot be `v1.begin()` - OP stores point xy coordinates in that vector

Comment: @Slava: `EuclideanDistance` takes `iterator` for container of `double`. It would be clearer if OP used `std::vector<Point>`, so it would be `EuclideanDistance(pt, expected_pt) < Epsilon`.

Comment: @Jarod42 if OP would use `Point` then `v1` would be an object of that type and you would not need `v1.begin()` either.

Comment: @Slava: `v1`, as `dv[x]`, are `vector` to be passed to `EuclideanDistance` with their iterators.

Comment: @Jarod42 I see, my mistake

Comment: Maybe use boost geometry library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @Slava In my case points can be any dimensionality vectors. Only during the execution, I will get these points from the external program and my goal is to store them in some good container and later to check if the new points are already in this container. This allows me to avoid lots of expensive procedures. In my case, efficiency really matters, and in general, I can have thousands of ~50-dimensional points (vectors), thus the right container and the algorithm can have a huge impact on the performance.

Comment: @Remis I see, but your algo should not work on points with different dimentions at the same time, correct? Then I would make template method on `int N` and use `std::array<double,N>` - that will guarantee points of the same dimentions. With `vector` you have to make sure that dimentions are the same, otherwise for example `EuclideanDistance` will crash

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> and was also trying to use std::find_if() without any success, as it accepts only unary predicate.

That's all you want anyway. The single argument is going to be the elements of the vector you're looking in.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> dv{
    {0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}};

std::vector<double> v1 {0.0001, 1.0};

auto find_result =
    std::find_if(begin(dv), end(dv), [&v1](std::vector<double> const &dve) {
      assert(dve.size() == v1.size());
      return EuclideanDistance(begin(dve), end(dve), begin(v1)) < 0.001;
    });
```

---

On another note, if your points are all a fixed dimension then using `vector<double>` probably is not the right representation. A `tuple<double,double>`, or an `array<double 2>`, or a custom class that has overloaded operators would probably all be appropriate replacements.

Comment: In my case, all points are n-dimensional vectors. However, only during execution, I will know the exact dimensions (n) of these points, i.e., for the different runs dimensionality of these points can differ. However, during the same run, all points have the same dimensionality. Thus, my goal is to choose the right container to store these points and later to use, an efficient algorithm to check if a new point is already in this container.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there in-house an STL algorithm to achieve the same goal? If no,
>   how could I improve my code? For example, I'm not sure how could I use
>   any distance function in check_in() instead of EuclideanDistance()?

Non exactly STL (if I'm not wrong), but...

As suggested by others, instead of a `std::vector<double>`, for points coordinates, you should consider `std::tuple<double, double, ...>` or, if they are 2D points (your case, if I'm not wrong), `std::pair<double, double>`.

But there is another tamplated class that I suggest you (but only for 2D points, not for 3D points): `std::complex<T>`

Your `dv` could be

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>> dv { {0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0} };
```

The new point

```
std::complex<double>  v1 {0.0001, 1.0};
```

Another suggestion: avoid the square root (it's costly to compute); check the square of the distance against the square of `Epsilon`; using `std::norm` of the difference of a couple of complex numbers you get exactly (if I'm not wrong) the square of the distance

Using `std::complex<double>`, the example from bames53 become simply

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
 {
   std::vector<std::complex<double>> dv
    { {0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0} };

   std::complex<double> v1 {0.0001, 1.0};

   auto find_result =
      std::find_if(begin(dv), end(dv), [&v1](std::complex<double> const &dve)
                   { return std::norm(v1-dve) < 0.000001; });

   std::cout << *find_result << std::endl;  // print (0,1)

   return 0;
 }
```

**--- EDIT ---**

> I wonder if AshleysBrain suggestion
>   (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451045/3737891) to use std::set instead
>   of std::vector could make any difference having a container of
>   floating points?

I don't think that the "floating point" component is important in choosing between `std::vector` and `std::set`.

By example, if (for your application) it's important to mantain the order of insertion of points, you should use `std::vector` (or `std::queue`); if you have to do a lot of searches, I think is better `std::set` (or `std::multiset` if you use point with molteplicity`).

If you decide to use `std::complex<double>`, I give you another suggestion: give a look at `std::valarray`.

I don't know what exactly do you want to do with your points but... I suppose can be useful.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

From your comment ("In my case points can be any dimensionality vectors...") I understand that the suggestion to use `std::complex<double>` for point coordinates (or `std::pair<double, double>`, or `std::tuple<double, double, ...>`) is inapplicable.

So i suggest to use, instead of `std::vector<double>`, `std::array<double, N>` where `N` is the dimension of the point.

I mantain my suggestion to avoid square root and check square of distance against square of `Epsilon`.

My third suggestion is to use `std::inner_product()` in the following way (example with `N == 3`)

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
 {
   std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> dv
    { {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}}, {{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}},
      {{0.0, 1.0, 0.0}}, {{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}},
      {{1.0, 1.0, 0.0}}, {{1.0, 0.0, 1.0}},
      {{0.0, 1.0, 1.0}}, {{1.0, 1.0, 1.0}} };

   std::array<double, 3> v1 { {0.0001, 1.0, -0.0001} };

   auto result = std::find_if(dv.cbegin(), dv.cend(),
           [&v1](std::array<double, 3> const & dve)
            { return std::inner_product(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(),
                 dve.cbegin(), 0.0, std::plus<double>(),
                 [](double d1, double d2){ auto d = d1-d2; return d*d; })
                 < 0.00001; });

   std::cout << "result: ";

   for ( const auto & d : *result )
      std::cout << '(' << d << ')';

   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

The output is

```
result: (0)(1)(0)
```

Sorry again for my English.