# How do I check if a element is not present inside of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

This compiles and runs ok on Visual C++ 2010 Express but it only checks against the [2] element: "Fish".

```
int main()
    {
        vector<string> words;
        string temp;
        vector<string> disliked(3);
        disliked[0] = "Broccoli";
        disliked[1] = "Mushrooms";
        disliked[2] = "Fish";
        while (cin >> temp)
            words.push_back(temp);
        cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << endl;
        for (int i=0; i<words.size(); ++i) {
            if (words[i]!=disliked[2])
                cout << words[i] << " ";
            else cout << "BLEEP" << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        keep_window_open();
        return 0;
    }
```

How do I make it check against ALL vector elements without typing:

```
if (words[i]!=disliked[0] && words[i]!=disliked[1] && words[i]!=disliked[2])
```

? Any other advices of how to make it better or more elegant?

Comment: I happen to like broccoli, mushrooms, and fish.

Comment: Me too! Don't worry, it's only a silly exercise in Stroustrup's book about Programming with C++. :)

Comment: I like mushrooms and fish more than broccoli. Broccoli is ok too though. Just not as good as mushrooms and fish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find an item in a std::vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-stdvector)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (std::find(disliked.begin(), disliked.end(), words[i]) == disliked.end()) {
   cout << words[i] << " ";
} else {
   cout << "BLEEP" << " ";
}
```

If you replace `std::vector<string> disliked(3);` with `std::set<string> disliked;` it works faster.

```
std::set<string> disliked;
disliked.insert("Broccoli");
disliked.insert("Mushrooms");
disliked.insert("Fish");
//....

if (disliked.find(words[i]) == disliked.end()) {
   cout << words[i] << " ";
} else {
   cout << "BLEEP" << " ";
}
```

Comment: +1, just fix the typo with the `std::set` constructor.  It shouldn't take any arguments.

Comment: @Charles: I took the liberty of fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can simply use `std::find` to search for the word in the vector.  But in general, vectors aren't meant for this sort of random-access lookup.  You might want to consider using an `std::set` to store the foods you don't like.

Then you can just say:

```
std::set<std::string> dislike;
dislike.insert("Broccoli");
dislike.insert("Mushrooms");
dislike.insert("Fish");

...

if (dislike.find("whatever") != dislike.end()) std::cout << "BLEEP" << std::endl;
```

Also, consider using an alternative expletive to "BLEEP".

Comment: You say "vectors aren't meant for this sort of lookup". I wonder why. Actually, the expression if (words[i]!=disliked[0,2]) /* notice the 0 */ is accepted and can be run but it still gives me a Bleep only for Fish.

Comment: Because when you search the vector for a word, you have to scan through the entire vector.  This is what the `std::find` function actually does, resulting in O(N) running time.  With `std::set`, each lookup is only O(Log(N)) running time, which is much faster.  Although for only 3 items there won't be any noticeable difference.

Comment: Also, that `disliked[0,2]` isn't doing what you think it's doing.  It doesn't mean you're actually comparing `words[i]` to elements 0 through 2 in the vector.  It's just a (misuse) of the (mostly useless) comma operator from C.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the most difficult part in learning any language I guess. Sometimes the compiler allows you do things without complaining and *you think* it has worked the way you implied.

Comment: @Kensai: You need to crank up your compiler's warning levels. Then it should say "WARNING: left operand of comma operator has no effect" or something like that.

Comment: FredOverflow, thanks for the advice. How do I do that on MS VC++ 2010 Express?! (please don't shoot the newbie) :p

Answer (score 2):

C++0x introduces three algorithms that you might want to check out: `all_of`, `any_of` and `none_of`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
{
    if (any_of(disliked.begin(),
               disliked.end(),
               bind2nd(equal_to<string>(), words[i])))
    {
        cout << "BLEEP" << " ";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << words[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

But as Alexey already pointed out, in this specific case, you are probably better off with a `std::set`. You could also do a `binary_search`on the vector, but then you have to make sure its sorted.

(Also note that I changed the loop counter type from `int` to `vector<string>::size_type`.)

Comment: Impressive! I'm looking forward to C++0x's new facilities.

Comment: @Kensai: Note that the implementation of `any_of` is almost trivial. In case your "impressive" comment is referring to `bind2nd` and `equal_to`, that's good old C++98.

Answer (score 1):

While other methods including set or std::find are actually very good and fast,
you should be able to understand how to make it by yourself.
If you want to check **all** elements in `words` against **all** elements in `disliked` you actually need another `for` loop.

```
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
     bool found = false;
     for (std::size_t j = 0; j < disliked.size(); ++j) {
        if (words[i] == disliked[j]) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      if (not found)    
        cout << words[i] << " ";
      else
        cout << "BLEEP" << " ";
    }
```

This is basically the code you will call using `std::find`. Note that the `find` method of `std::set` use a different approach often implemented using [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) which is much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to check are the all elements the same. The best idea is to use set. If you need vector for something else the fastest way is to sort the vector, go through it and check if any subsequent elements are same (O(n log(n) + n)). If your vectors aren't big the answer with 2 for loops will do the job (O(n^2)).