# SEARCH or FOUND inside of vector problem

Tags: c++, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find an item in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-stdvector)

Given these two classes:

```
class Book
{
private:

  string title;
  int category;

public:

  Book(const string& , int num);
}

Book(const string& name, int num)
  :title(name), category(num)
{ }



class Reader
{
private:

string reader_name;
vector <Book> bookLists;

public:

void add(const Book &ref);
};

void add(const Book& ref)
{
    // My problem is here.
}
```

I want to search inside the vector of Book. If the Book is in the vector of Book, it does nothing. If the Book is not in the vector of Book `bookLists.push_back(ref);`

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-stdvector) useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
std::find(bookLists.begin(), bookLists.end(), bookItemToBeSearched)!=bookLists.end().
```

`std::find` returns:
An iterator to the first element in the range that matches value OR
If no element matches, the function returns last.

Check more about the `std::find` algorithm ***[here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find.html)***.

Comment: Thank you!

 if Find == vector.end() what does it mean?? 


and Find != vector.end() ??

Comment: @newb: Take a look at the reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Answer (score 0):

```
void add(const Book& ref)
{
   if(std::find(bookLists.begin(), bookLists.end(), ref)==bookLists.end())
   {
       bookLists.push_back(ref);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Do I need to state  any vector iterator??

Comment: You will need to define Book::operator== for this to work, since std::find cannot "guess" on what criteria you want to compare the books (are the titles sufficient ? do they actually need to be the same physical object ?). For example, you could define bool Book::operator==(const Book &other) const { return title == other.title && category == other.category; }

Comment: Thank you ZeRemz.
I didn't know I have to define Book::operator==

that's why I was keep getting compiline error