# Trying to use qsort with vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, qsort

I'm trying to learn c++ and was trying using sort and qsort. sort() works just fine 
but qsort doesn't, I don't know why, so can you help me please
this is the code I was trying to compile

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<algorithm>


using namespace std;

int compvar(const void *one, const void *two)
{
    int a = *((int*)one);
    int b = *((int*)two);
    if (a<b)
       return -1;
    if (a == b)
       return 0;
    return 1;   

}

void bvect(vector<int> &vec, int num)
{
     srand(time(NULL));
     for(int i=0; i<num; ++i)
             vec.push_back(rand()%1000 + 1);
}

void showvec(vector<int> vec)
{
     for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i)
         cout<<vec[i]<<endl;
}


int main()
{
    vector<int>numbers;
    bvect(numbers, 1000);
    showvec(numbers);
    qsort(numbers.begin(), numbers.size(), sizeof(int), compvar);
    showvec(numbers);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Allow me to be the first to advise that you "Just say NO!". Using `qsort` on a vector is just plain nuts.

Comment: *Why do you even want to use `qsort`?!*

Comment: You seem to be making the assumption that your implementation uses raw pointers as vector iterators.  Does it?  Regardless, your code should not assume it does.  Use `&numbers[0]` instead of `numbers.begin()`.

Comment: if you are learning C++, forget about qsort and other C-functions

Comment: use comparator as here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/   and also you should call srand only once so it would be better if you call it in main function

Comment: `int a = *((int*)one);` the outermost parentheses aren't needed.

Comment: @Jupiter - the comparator looks just fine. What do you think should be different?

Comment: @Pete Becker "if" statement looks like overhead)

Comment: @Jupiter - how would you change it? I don't see much extra there.

Comment: @PeteBecker: The final `if (a == b) return 0; return 1;` could be replaced by `return (a > b);` but that is minor compared to the horror of not using `std::sort` in the first place.

Comment: @Blastfurnace - the optimizer will make good sense of all of this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First of all, DON'T.

If you just want to muck about, you can replace iterators with actual pointers:

```
qsort(&numbers[0], numbers.size(), sizeof(int), compvar);
```

Apart from not doing all the work `std::sort` does, there is one unexpected thing about `qsort`. It is *slower*.

1. `sort (myvector1.begin(), myvector1.end());`
2. `sort (myvector2.begin(), myvector2.end(), myfunction);`
3. `sort (myvector3.begin(), myvector3.end(), myobject);`
4. `qsort(&myvector4[0], myvector4.size(), sizeof(int), cmyfunction);`

4 is the slowest, followed by 2 (function pointer passed to `std::sort`). 1 and 3 (default and functor) are the fastest (compiled with gnu's g++ with -O3 flag).

Comment: Thanks for the answers.It worked!. I know qsort() is slower than sort() and that's what I was trying to test, I'm taking a programming course and the professor told us to test them both.again thanks