# Passing vector to qsort

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am trying to sort the "sth" integer value within the vector of class Entry using qsort. The code for the same is as follows. But after applying qsort, also the values remain the same. When I tried to print the values in cmpfunc2(), I found that 0 0 is getting printed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Entry{public:
int id;
int sth;

Entry(int,int);
};
 Entry::Entry(int a,int b){
  id=a;
  sth=b;
}
int cmpfunc2 (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   cout<<(*(Entry *)a).sth<<"  "<<(*(Entry *)b).sth <<endl;
   return ( (*(Entry*)a).sth - (*(Entry*)b).sth );
}
int main(){
vector<Entry> entries;

entries.push_back(Entry(2,3));
entries.push_back(Entry(21,14));
entries.push_back(Entry(54,12));

qsort(&entries, entries.size(),sizeof(Entry),cmpfunc2);
  for(int i=0;i<entries.size();i++)
  cout<<entries[i].sth<<endl;
}
```

Comment: &entries is vector<Entry>*. You need &entries[0]

Comment: Just curious, why use `qsort` instead of `std::sort`?

Comment: @user2451677 You should make this an answer ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to use qsort with vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308243/trying-to-use-qsort-with-vector)

Comment: @Paul, nothing just wanted to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

Change this statement

```
qsort(&entries, entries.size(),sizeof(Entry),cmpfunc2);
```

to

```
qsort( entries.data(),  entries.size(), sizeof( Entry ), cmpfunc2 );
```

However it would be better to use standard algorithm `std::sort`  declared in header `<algorithm>`. For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

bool cmpfunc2 ( const Entry &a, const Entry &b )
{
   return ( a.sth < b.sth );
}

// ...

std::sort( entries.begin(), entries.end(), cmpfunc2 );
```

Or you could use `std::stable_sort`

```
std::stable_sort( entries.begin(), entries.end(), cmpfunc2 );
```

Also consider the posiibility to compare objects of type `Entry` as objects of type `std::pair`. In this case objects with equal sth will be sorted according to id. For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

//... 

bool cmpfunc2 ( const Entry &a, const Entry &b )
{
   return ( std::make_pair( a.sth, a.id )  < std::make_pair( b.sth, b.id ) );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'm making my comment as an answer.

First, looking on the documentation of [qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort).
First parameter **ptr** - pointer to the array to sort.

So if you really want to use qsort with a vector (it's very strange, std::sort is there) the answer to your question is the answer to question "*How to conver a vector to a raw array?*".

You need to use a small hack - **&entries[0]** - pointer to first element of a vector. It's works, because elements in a vector, regarding to the standard, have contiguous memory location and this is the same as with raw array.

In new standard there is **data()** function member for the vector. You can use this member-function

Comment: Note `&entries[0]` is UB if `entries.empty()` is true.  `.datta()` in that case returns `nullptr`.

Comment: Of cource. I wrote without this note due to example from the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in `&entries` to `qsort` it should be:

```
qsort(&entries[0], entries.size(), sizeof(Entry), cmpfunc2);
```

Answer (score 1):

**A)** use `std::sort()` with `entries.begin()` and `entries.end()`  -> faster

OR

**B)** use `qsort()` with  `&entries.front()` instead of `&entries` -> slower

Comment: Not necessarily slower. Depends on implementation. I've seen qsort being faster, especially if it is specialised for single data type.