# sorting large arrays causing my program to freeze while running

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am sorting an array of unknown length. When I sort the code with any amount of length less then 2101 it sorts just fine but once I increase that number it stops sorting. I am unsure if it is because of my computer's memory or from my code itself. For the sort, I am using the quick sort algorithm.

a copy of the sort is below if anyone can spot a problem

```
int partitionFunct(Person arr[], int low, int high) {

    Person pivotVal=arr[low];
    int i=low+1;
    int j=high;
    while(i<=j)
    {
        while(arr[i]<pivotVal&&i<=j)
            i++;

        while(pivotVal<arr[j]&&i<=j)
            j--;
        if((i<j))
        {
            Person temp=arr[i];
            arr[i++]=arr[j];
            arr[j--]=temp;
        }
    }
    arr[low]=arr[j];
    arr[j]=pivotVal;
    return j;
}
void quickSortInternal (Person arr[], int low, int high) {

    if (low >= high) return; 
    int pivot=partitionFunct( arr,  low,  high);
    quickSortInternal(arr,low,pivot-1);
    quickSortInternal(arr,pivot+1,high);
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Maybe you can use std::sort() as an alternative

Comment: The problem with Quicksort is that it has a worst case running time of O(n^2).  It's easy for an O(n^2) algorithm to look like it's hung even when it's not, simply because you've run out of patience waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Run it in a debugger and when it "freezes" break out then you can more easily see why it isn't making progress.

Comment: *I am sorting an array of unknown length* -- you need to show a [mcve].  The length must be known (either at compile time or run time), otherwise you wouldn't know what values to set `low` and `high` to.

Comment: With an already-sorted array the run-time bounds are known (with unsorted data it could be faster or slower depending on the data)  And with optimization the algorithm runs really fast even with many thousands of items.  Here are some timings for an already sorted array with different amounts of elements: https://quick-bench.com/q/MT1J8Q2xGY3ZkwEf8mLyfKHZt5E

Comment: Update: My code was accessing past the bounds of the array and when I set the array to be larger it caused it to attempt to access memory it didn't have access to. The problem has been solved

Answer (score -2):

try this from : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/

with more than 2000 elements.

```
/* qsort example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* qsort */

int values[] = { 40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25 };

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main ()
{
  int n;
  qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
  for (n=0; n<6; n++)
     printf ("%d ",values[n]);
  return 0;
}
```

it might interest you : [Trying to use qsort with vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308243/trying-to-use-qsort-with-vector)

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?  They have clearly written a C++ program to perform quicksort and are having trouble debugging it.  Your advice apparently is to use `qsort` from the C standard library.  You may as well have provided a Java or Python example instead.

Comment: I think OP doesn't know if the problem is low RAM or the algorithm itself, or its code precisely. A comparison with working code can lead it in the right direction. He is not the first programmer to find bugs in this particular algorithm as you can see in the link i suggested.

Comment: So why not provide a C++ example? It still wouldn't be an answer, though. Also, 2000 != large.

Comment: may be tomorrow... i will see an interesting answer under  mine. why you don't ...

Comment: I agree that a C++ example would be more appropriate.  Especially since `std::sort` is known to work, whereas this example has a critical error in the `compare` function that has incorrect (and implementation-defined) behavior if provided with large positive or negative values.  However that is still speculative because the OP has not shown enough code to indicate that they're doing other stuff correctly (such as allocating memory).  The reason there aren't answers is because of that, and nobody is wiling to critically analyze the logic in the OP's example, because it's a job for the debugger.