# Find an element in a vector array

Tags: c++, vector, find, c++builder, vcl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find an item in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-stdvector)

I am using C++ Builder to create a VCL Forms application. I also have a vector array of appointment objects that each have a name, type, reminder date/time, a date/time, location and comments.

I am wanting to implement a find feature that will let a user find an appointment given certain criteria.

The user can choose to find an appointment in the vector array by either choosing the name, type etc or a combination of each.

What would be the best programming concept to use for this situation? The vector is not large. No more than 10 or 20 elements.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a vector, or an array of vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::find_if(A.begin(),A.end(),isthatit(conditions));
```

where `isthatit` is a predicate object constructed from conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::find_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and define the required predicate (if C++11 you can use lambda function).

See online demo http://ideone.com/Md7sp.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many criterias you should think about 
Boost.MultiIndex container which targets different search indexes.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Index? "No more than 10 or 20 elements"… Index? ;-)