# Vector. Checking to see if it contains "Key". C++

Tags: c++, vector, contain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find an item in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-stdvector)

Hey like the title suggests i would like to check to see if the vector contains the string "Key".  I have been looking around on Google and i cant find anything in the vector library.  Can anybody help me with this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's why we have algorithms :) They work on any container (and more), rather than having to reimplement them for each one. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: "The vector?"  What vector?  I don't see any vector here.

Comment: @chris very good example :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) for that. Assuming you have an `std::vector` full of `std::strings`:

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::find

std::vector<std::string> v = ....;
std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), "Key");
bool found = it != v.end();
```

Comment: Hey,  Im getting an error.  Data Member initialized is not allowed.

Comment: Wow, you asked this 10 years ago and still got benefit from this conversation. Stackoverflow is awesome!