# Vector Iteration and Removal in C++

Tags: c++, vector, iteration

I am trying to iterate over a vector and remove the first occurrence of an object. I keep getting a compile error (using g++), but I am removing it the way stackoverflow answers and other sources suggested removing it. There is probably something super simple that I'm missing, so another set of eyes would be great too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;

bool Garage::remove(const Car &car){
assert(!empty());

int size = v.size();
for(vector<Car>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it){
    if(it -> Car::make() == car.Car::make()){
        it = v.erase(it);
        assert(v.size() == size - 1);
        return true;
     }
 }
 return false;
}
```

The compile error is
     error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector::erase(const Car&)'

Comment: Please don't use the homework tag. [It's deprecated.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: You should search for the _erase/remove_ idiom...

Comment: The error doesn't seem to match your code. Are you sure your code doesn't say `erase(*it)` or something like that?

Comment: @chris Sorry, I don't come here often so I didn't realize the tag was no longer used. People used to tell me to add it.

Comment: I tried it and *it and both gave me the same error.

Comment: I did look at the erase/remove algorithm and it seemed like it was for erasing multiple occurrences, but I just want to erase the first occurrence.

Comment: Something simple like `v.erase(std::find(...))` would work. Make sure that it is found, though, before erasing it.

Comment: `Car::make()` is static function, so `if(it -> Car::make() == car.Car::make())` will always evaluate to true?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to erase using a const_iterator.  Since you're trying to modify the vector, switch to a regular iterator.

```
for(vector<Car>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it){
```

This works:

```
int main()
{
   vector<int> ints;

   for (vector<int>::iterator iter = ints.begin();iter != ints.end();++iter)
   {
      ints.erase(iter);
   }
}
```

This doesn't:

```
int main()
{
   vector<int> ints;

   for (vector<int>::const_iterator iter = ints.begin();iter != ints.end();++iter)
   {
      ints.erase(iter);
   }
}
```

Error when using a const_iterator:

```
test.cpp:18:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int>::erase(std::vector<int>::const_iterator&)’
```

Comment: I removed const and it compiles now. Just have to test it a ton.

Comment: Just a note that on compilers following the C++11 standard, it *will* work with a `const_iterator`.

Comment: @Bo Persson With which version of gcc?  I am running 4.6.3 (g++ -std=c++0x) and it doesn't support const_iterator.  I see where it is specified here, but gcc doesn't support it yet? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Answer (score 1):

[It appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-stdvector) that you'll need to use [find](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find.html) to find the index of the element and subsequently [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) it. I say "appears" because I'm not a C++ programmer.