# Specifying a range of indices

Tags: c++

Inside a function I have a while loop that looks like the following:

```
void unpack(std::vector<std::string>& leftcol, std::vector<std::string>& rightcol, std::vector<std::string> origv, std::string perm) {
    ....
    while(perm != origv[0] && perm != origv[1])
    ....
}
```

What I'd like to do is compare `perm` to every element in `origv`. But it happens that if I do it in sequence, the while loop will loop forever. The reason for this is that perm is permuted until it matches one of the `origv` elements. And there's only one that matches.

Is there a way to set `perm` to compare with each element in `origv` without looping through the vector?

So if `origv` had three elements, I want to be able to check each element against `perm` in the same way the above code does for two elements.

To be clear, what I'm trying to say is I can't do something like this:

```
for(std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0; i < origv.size(); i++)
    while(perm != origv[i])
```

Comment: what about `leftcol` and `rightcol` ? They are scaring

Comment: @P0W. They aren't used until the loop exits so don't mind those.

Comment: To be clear, you want something like `while(perm is not in origv) {do something}`, right?

Comment: @Kaiged. Yes that's correct.

Comment: @Dochevsky, Pete Becker beat me to it, but I think his answer is what you want.

Comment: This is related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/571394/1272627).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the constraint that you're describing, but the way to test whether an object compares equal to an element of a collection is to use `std::find`:

```
while (std::find(origv.begin(), origv.end(), perm) == origv.end()) {
    // perm not found
}
```

Comment: Basically I'm altering `perm` until it matches one of the string elements of the vector. There's only one element in the vector that will match it correctly after however many alterations. Anyway your method works. Thanks.

Comment: @Dochevsky Please make sure you're not having [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/232397)

Comment: @Dochevsky - so, inside the loop you're modifying `perm`? That makes sense.