# How to find the positions of an item in a std::vector

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

My question is very similar to [How to find an item in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-stdvector) However, I want to go further, suppose the item I am searching for appears several times in the vector, and I want to obtain its positions in the vector as well. For example, the vector I have is `[ 1 3 4 3 7]`, and the item I want to search is `3`. Then the positions of the item is `1` and `3`. Using the `std::find` function, I can only obtain its first position in the vector. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just stick it in a while loop,

```
    auto i = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), n);
    std::vector<std::size_t> result;
    while(i != v.end())
    {
      result.push_back(std::distance(v.begin(), i));
      i = std::find(i + 1, v.end(), n);
    }
```

Comment: +1, but you should use `size_t` instead of `unsigned` for this purpose - your code could fail if these don't match in size (such as a huge vector on a 64-bit system).

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::find` successive times, and then put all the results together. Use as `first` of the range in which you find, the position that the previous `std::find` returned to you plus one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::find` multiple times:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// fill the vector with numbers
std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin();
while (it != vec.end())
{
    it = std::find(it, vec.end(), 3);
    // do something with *it
    if (it != vec.end())
        it++;
}
```

Or you can simply use `std::for_each`:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// fill the vector with numbers
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](int i)
{
    if (i == 3)
    {
        // do something
    }
});
```

If you are looking for the indexes/iterators for the items, you can simply use a custom loop:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// fill the vector with numbers
std::vector<int> results;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
{
    if (vec[i] == 3)
    {
        results.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

`results` will then hold all of the indexes for elements matching your criteria (in this case, `==3`).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but if I use std::for_each method, I donot think I can get the item's position.  if (i==3) { //do something} How could I get the item's position?

Comment: @feelfree Are you looking to get it's index or it's iterator?

Comment: I am looking for its index.

Comment: @feelfree Updated to include that option.