# Loop over a structure of vector<string> in C++

Tags: c++, loops, vector, structure

Question:  Is there a better way to loop through all the vectors in the structure than by calling them one by one as shown in the example?  #

I am building a classifier.  There are several categories of items each represented by a vector of string.  Each of the vectors will be fairly small, < 100 elements.  I have read the examples in the following link:

[How to find if an item is present in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-stdvector)

Here is a simplified example of the code that I am implementing.  The code compiles and runs but seems clunky to me.  Thanks in advance.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Categories
{
    vector <string> cars;
    vector <string> food;
};

struct ThingsType
{
    Categories iLike;
    Categories dontLike;
};

typedef vector<string>::const_iterator vIter;

int FindValue(vector<string>& vec, string keyWord)
{
    int indx = -1;
    vIter iter = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), keyWord);
    if (iter != vec.end()){
        // found it 
        std::cout << "Value:  " << *iter << " found in location:  " << iter - vec.begin() << endl;
        indx = iter - vec.begin();
    }
    else
    {
        // did not find it.
        std::cout << "Value:  " << keyWord << " not found." << endl;
    }
    return indx;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int result[10];
    ThingsType things;
    things.iLike.cars = { "Mustang", "Pinto" };
    things.dontLike.food = { "Squash" };
    string item("Pinto");
    // I want to loop over all vectors searching for items
    result[0] = FindValue(things.iLike.cars, item);
    result[1] = FindValue(things.iLike.food, item);
    // . . .
    result[9] = FindValue(things.dontLike.food, item);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change: `int FindValue(vector<string>& vec, string keyWord)` by `int FindValue(vector<string>& vec, const string& keyWord)`, you are copying the string every time that call `FindValue`. Other possible improvement is sort the array of categories and find with `lower_bound`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the struct, and store pointers to each struct member in a list or vector.

```
struct Categories
{
    vector <string> cars;
    vector <string> food;
};

std::vector<std::vector<string>*> members;
Categories cat;
members.push_back(&cat.cars);  // add a pointer to the cars struct member
members.push_back(&cat.food);  // add a pointer to the food struct member
```

Now you can iterate via members, or access via the struct.

```
for(std::vector<string>* member: members)
{
    for(string s: *member)
    {

    } 
}
```

Or you could just forego the structure altogether and use the vector of vectors, that way you can iterate the "members" while still allowing O(1) access time for each member.

```
 const int CARS = 0;
 const int FOOD = 1; 
 members[CARS].push_back(car);   // add a car
 members[FOOD].push_back(food);  // add food

 // iterate cars
 for(string car: members[CARS])
 {
    // do something
 }
```

Comment: I like the vector of vectors.  Combine that with enum { CARS, FOOD } and now I can access the vectors with members[CARS].  I sure like python where I can iterate over things like enum.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a std::map

```
using namespace std;

typedef set<string> CategoryType;

struct ThingsType
{
    map<string, CategoryType> iLike;
    map<string, CategoryType> dontLike;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ThingsType things;
    things.iLike['cars'].insert("Mustang");
    things.iLike['cars'].insert("Pinto");
    things.iLike['food'].insert("Squash");

    string item("Pinto");
    // I want to loop over all vectors searching for items
    for(map<string, CategoryType>::const_iterator i = things.iLike.begin(); i != things.iLike.end(); i++) {
        if (i->second.find(item) != set::end)
            cout << "I like " << item << endl;
    }

    for(map<string, CategoryType>::const_iterator i = things.dontLike.begin(); i != things.dontLike.end(); i++) {
        if (i->second.find(item) != set::end)
            cout << "I don't like " << item << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution.  Thanks.  Are there any drawbacks to using set and map over vector?

Comment: With sets and maps you can find a value in O(ln n) time as opposed to O(n) time with a vector.  As far as disadvantages go, there is no ordering of items in most set and map types and you will be using a negligibly greater amount of memory for each item.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`std::unordered_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) would be better in this case.

```
#include<unordered_set>

struct Categories{
    std::unordered_set <std::string> cars;
    std::unordered_set <std::string> food;
};

struct ThingsType{
    Categories iLike;
    Categories dontLike;
};

int main(){
    std::unordered_set<std::string>::iterator result[10];
    ThingsType things;
    things.iLike.cars = { "Mustang", "Pinto" };
    things.dontLike.food = { "Squash" };
    string item("Pinto");
    result[0] = things.iLike.cars(item);
    result[1] = things.iLike.food(item);
    // . . .
    result[9] = things.dontLike.food(item);
}
```