# What does "!=vector.end()" mean in find statement?

Tags: c++, vector

This [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/571405/1816774) states the following code:

```
std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item)!=vector.end()
```

The first part I understand, we are going to find *item* between the begin and end of *vector*. But why the `!=vector.end()`. Something like: *"if the end of the vector does not equal what is found"*? Should this code be in an `if` statement?

Comment: Have you actually checked the documentation for std::find?

Comment: Yes, the result of the expression is a bool.  It should either be an if statement or store the result in a variable.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: This question is not asking for an off-site resource. Closevoter, please lay off the drugs while using SO. Ta.

Comment: The above expression is meant as a replacement for `item_present` in the question you've linked to

Comment: Guys, I think he's saying the line of code is literally what's above, which is an expression for which the result is thrown away.

Comment: @mbgda maybe not only guys are here, but I think you are right. Tim don't take that answer literally!

Comment: If you read the question that the linked answer is from it's pretty clear that it was meant to be a substitute into the question code.  There's also another answer that shows complete usage in code.

Comment: Yeah @mbgda please be gender-neutral and check your privilege at all times!! Thanks!! :-)

Comment: +1 This question is not lazy or stupid but is asking _why_ an end iterator has these semantics and for a way to make that intuitive. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I didn't see the first line that links what you're referring to until you pointed it out.  This  definitely could have been 30 seconds with google instead of being posted here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector::end` returns a "special" iterator. It does not give you the last element, but *one past the end*.

It is also used to indicate "no match" or "no element", much like you might have used "-1" to signal an error condition back in the 1970s.

That's what you're seeing here.

Comment: @Ulterior: Would you care to explain what makes it a "noob answer", oh great and wise one?