# In C++, how to find certain items in the vector of objects by giving the member of a object?

Tags: c++, object, vector

For example, I have defined the class foo and the vector vec:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class foo {
public:
    foo(int flag, char ch):flag(flag), ch(ch) {}
    int flag;
    char ch;
};
int main(void)
{
    vector<foo> vec;
    vec.push_back(foo(1,'a'));
    vec.push_back(foo(2,'b'));
    vec.push_back(foo(3,'c'));
    //blabla...
}
```

I've found how to find the single element: [How to find an item in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-stdvector)
But now I want to find an object by just giving a char, say, 'b'. How can I achieve this goal efficiently?

Comment: do you know how to iterate over a vector and use the == operator?

Comment: You can also use `std::find`.

Comment: @DavidHaim I know that, but I feel it's inefficient when the vector becomes too large. So ...^_^

Comment: Aren’t you looking for `std::map`?

Comment: usually search through an array is in O(N) complexity

Comment: @HaroldHuang If you want efficient searches, use a sorted vector and binary search, or don't use a vector.

Comment: @Melebius No... It's just a simple example class... I think I need vector more than map.

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia I don't know how to implement that, so can you show me an example? Just use the code I've given.

Comment: @HaroldHuang I wont be difficult to implement. Follow this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `std::find_if` for this:

```
 //c++14
 std::find_if(std::begin(vec),std::end(vec),
              [](auto&& v) { return v.ch == 'b'; })

 //c++11
 std::find_if(std::begin(vec),std::end(vec),
              [](const foo& v) { return v.ch == 'b'; })
```

You could wrap this up in a function if you find yourself needing this pattern a number of times:

```
//c++14, c++11 version left as exercise
decltype(auto) find_foo (const std::vector<foo>& vec, char c)
{
    return std::find_if(std::begin(vec),std::end(vec),
                        [c](auto&& v) { return v.ch == c; });
}
```

A better option might be to use a `std::unordered_map<char,int>` instead of a `std::vector<foo>`:

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<char,int> my_map;
    my_map['a'] = 1;
    my_map['b'] = 2;
    my_map['c'] = 3;

    cout << my_map['b']; //instead of that std::find_if nonsense
}
```

Comment: Em... Thank you for your answer but my compiler says that the `auto` in your first code block isn't allowed and I don't konw why. I'm using Visul Studio 2012.

Comment: That's a C++14 feature, just use `const foo&` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard algorithm `std::find_if` declared in header `<algorithm>`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class foo {
public:
    foo(int flag, char ch):flag(flag), ch(ch) {}
    int flag;
    char ch;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<foo> vec;

    vec.push_back(foo(1,'a'));
    vec.push_back(foo(2,'b'));
    vec.push_back(foo(3,'c'));

    char ch = 'b';
    auto it = std::find_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
                            [&]( const foo &f ) { return f.ch == ch; } );

    if ( it != vec.end() ) std::cout << it->flag << ' ' << it->ch << std::endl;

}
```

If your compiler supports C++14 then the lambda expression can be written also the following way

```
auto it = std::find_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
                        [ch = 'b']( const foo &f ) { return f.ch == ch; } );
```

The other approach is to make the seach as an interface of the class itself. For example

```
class foo {
public:
    foo(int flag, char ch):flag(flag), ch(ch) {}
    int flag;
    char ch;
    class find_by_ch
    {
    public:        
        find_by_ch( char ch ) : ch( ch ) {}
        bool operator ()( const foo &f ) const { return f.ch == ch; }
    private:
        char ch;
    };        
};

//...

auto it = std::find_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), foo::find_by_ch( 'b' ) );
```

Comment: @Harold Huang What is not clear? See also my updated post.:)

Comment: Oh, I've make myself clear. Thanks a million! The latter approach is inspiring.

Comment: But it seems that to accept multiple answers isn't allowed, I'm sorry.

Comment: I like the latter approach. Truly OOP.

Answer (score 1):

Define an implicit constructor for `foo` using only `char` as argument.

```
foo(char ch) : ch(ch), flag(int()) {
}
```

**OR** add default args to your existing constructor

```
foo(char ch, int flag = int()) : ch(ch), flag(flag) {
}
```

**AND** overload a comparison operator

```
bool operator ==(const char & rhs) {
    return ch == rhs;
}
```

You can then use `std::find` directly.

```
vector<foo>::iterator it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 'b');
if (it != vec.end()) {
    ...    // do something
}
```

A working code will then look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
    foo(char ch, int flag = int()) : flag(flag), ch(ch) {}
    int flag;
    char ch;
    inline bool operator ==(const char & rhs) { return ch == rhs; }
};

int main(void) {
    vector<foo> vec;
    vec.push_back(('a', 1));
    vec.push_back(('b', 2));
    vec.push_back(('c', 3));
    vector<foo>::iterator it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 'b');
    if (it != vec.end())
        cout << "found" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See http://ideone.com/ue907i demo.

Answer (score 0):

If the vector is sorted (as in your example), you can use lower_bound for logarithmic performance. If the vector is not sorted, you can use find for linear performance.