# Using std::find to locate a randomly generated number in a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

```
vector<int> v(n);
```

Given a vector of n randomly generated numbers, I want to set a random variable and determine if that variable is located in that vector using std::find algorithm.

```
int x = rand();
int p = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
```

When I first run this code, I get an error along the lines of "cannot convert iterator  to int in initialization".

Comment: Did you lookup what `std::find` returns?

Comment: lemme guess, you come from a Java/C# background?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find if an item is present in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-if-an-item-is-present-in-a-stdvector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

> Return value
>
> Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or last if no
>   such element is found.

To satisfy that using the example from the documentation

```
auto p = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
bool found = (p != v.end());
```

Found now contains if the value you mentioned was found or not.