# How to find out if a string is contained in any string of a std::vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector, find

Having a vector of hostnames, I want to pull off any hostname that contains any string from another vector.

Let's say that I have a 2D vector containing hostnames and IP addresses:

```
std::vector<std::vector<string>> hostnames = {{"Mike-computer","1.2.3.4"}, 
                                         {"John-computer","5.6.7.8"}, 
                                         {"Monica-computer","9.10.11.12"}};
```

And another vector containing target hostnames:

```
std::vector<string> targets = {"Mike", "Sophia"};
```

If any line in `hostnames` vector contains `"Mike"` or `"Sophia"`, pull off its info. In this example, `"Mike-Computer"` would be pulled off since it contains `"Mike"` from my `targets` vector.

I found on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-out-if-an-item-is-present-in-a-stdvector) that I can use `std::find` on my `targets` vector but it will not work if it is not an exact match. It would only work if I specifically says `"Mike-computer"` but I don't know the full hostnames of computers I query.

Here is the piece of code:

```
for (std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::iterator row = hostnames.begin(); row != hostnames.end(); ++row)
{
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col)
    {
        if ((std::find(targetsList.begin(), targetsList.end(), *col) != targetsList.end()))
        {
            std::cout << *col << " is a match" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use `<algorithm>`, the correct algorithm to search for a subsequence is [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search), not `std::find`.

Comment: Does it matter whether it's at index 0 or anywhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` has a [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) member function that will find if a string exists in another string.  You can use that to see if the host name contains the target name like

```
for (const auto& host : hostnames)
{
    for (const auto& target : tagets)
    {
        if (host[0].find(target) != std::string::npos)
            std::cout << "Found: " << host[0] << " with IP: " << host[1];
    }
}
```

I would also like to suggest that if you are always going to just have a host name and IP pair that you use a an actual data structure like

```
struct Computer
{
    std::string name;
    std::string IP;
};
```

So that

```
if (host[0].find(target) != std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "Found: " << host[0] << " with IP: " << host[1];
```

Would look like

```
if (host.name.find(target) != std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "Found: " << host.name << " with IP: " << host.IP;
```

Or at leas use a `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` so the code doesn't have "magic numbers" in it.

Comment: I tested both ways and they pull off the correct number of found hosts