# How to check if a vector contains a specific character within specified indices?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, vector

I would like to know how (if it is even possible) to search from the beginning of a vector up to a specified index if a character exists.

Pseudocode:

```
vector<char> a{a, b, c, d, e, f, /*...*/};

if (from a.begin() to a[2] b exists) {
... }
```

What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: the above does not appear to be valid c++ code, so it will be difficult for anybody to offer assistance

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-out-if-an-item-is-present-in-a-stdvector) could be of some use to you.

Comment: "Fastest and easiest" rarely go together well. Do you know of any (not fastest or easiest) way of doing this? Perhaps even a way that isn't quite working? If so, add it to the question. For some reason, people are more willing to respond to "fix my code" requests than to "write code for me" requests.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, and it doesn't seem like Google has any answers to my question either. That's why I asked here. Also, I removed easiest, as I am not interested in learning the easiest way to write code, but the most efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algorithms from standard take iterators, not container, so you can use them:

```
auto it = std::find(a.begin(), a.begin() + 2, 'b');
if (it != a.begin() + 2) {
    // found.
}
```

Comment: I haven't thought about that, at all! I will try to implement it in my code and reply if it doesn't work.

Comment: As long as we stick to `std::vector`, `std::any_of` would have same efficiency and be more explicit

Answer (score 1):

With these definitions:

```
vector<char> a = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' /*...*/};
char ch = 'x';
```

You can easily go for the following, starting after the first char (`+1`) and ending ignoring the two last elements (`-2`):

```
if (any_of(a.cbegin()+1, a.cend()-2, [&ch](auto &x){return x==ch; }))
    cout << "found !"<<endl; 
else cout << "not found! "<<endl;
```

You can also use the more classical [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) in the [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) library:

```
if (std::find(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), ch) !=a.cend()) 
   ...
```

If you want to start at a given offset or end ignoring some trailing elements, you can go iterator math on the start or end iterator:

```
if (std::find(a.cbegin()+3, a.cend(), ch) != a.cend()) 
    ...
```

If you do this often, and you're not intereste where in the vector the element is found, you could consider the following function:

```
template <class U, class W> 
bool myfind (const  U &v, size_t starto, size_t endo, const W& x) {
    if (starto>=endo || endo>=v.size())
        return false; 
    return std::find(v.begin()+starto, v.begin()+endo, x) != v.begin()+endo;
}
```

If you can go for `std::string` rather than `std::vector`, you could use the member function [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) which can take an offset as argument.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I was just editing in this direction ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
     vector<char> A;
     //initialize your vector here
     unsigned i;
     unsigned start, stop;
     //initialize the start and stop here
     for(i=start; i<stop; i++){
         if(A[i]=='b'){
             cout<<"character found!"<<endl;
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I am not looking to find the position of the element, but if an element exists within specified indexes.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you operate on non-sorted container (`std::vector` is one) I'd go for `std::any_of` to express your intention. It will have same efficiency as `std::find`

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> a{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
    // Checks range between 'b'...'d'
    if (std::any_of(a.begin() + 1, a.end() - 2, [](char c){return c == 'b';})) {
      // do stuff
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP wanted _0⇒2_, not _0⇒(n-2)_

Comment: What's the `return 10` about?

Comment: Ehm, does it really matter? This is just example usage of `any_of`. I believe OP can adjust it to his needs.

Comment: Well, yes, it matters. You're teaching. Why put things in a teaching example that don't make any sense, or that are wrong?

Comment: `contains a specific character within specified indices` - this is what is question about. Not any specific use case read from pseudocode. PS. I've used `return 10` out of curiosity to check whenever gcc will optimize whole call, it does.

Comment: Ad. `You're teaching.` added in edit: I am teaching, but I don't have to give him a fish, a rod should be enough. Why wouldn't I provide more generic example to trigger OP to think about iteration calculations, that you can do both `begin()  +1` and `end() - 2`, not just exact case which he asked?

Comment: All I'm asking is why you gave the wrong solution (2 from end, rather than 2 from beginning) and threw in the highly unusual `return 10` without explaining it. You can fix that quite easily. This has nothing to do with "teach a man to fish", it's more "don't throw a man to the sharks"

Comment: Revenge-downvoting my answer doesn't help either

Comment: I am afraid I am not the downvoter. I don't agree doing `begin() + 1` and `end() - 2` is wrong solution, neither the "shark". I've removed `return 10` if it bothers you so much.

Comment: I just wanted you to explain it. Oh well.

Comment: Explanation about "compiler can inline optimize the code I've provided into single assembler call" would be more like shark ;) SO complains already about long discussion, I think we should stop here.

Answer (score -1):

The others are right that, since algorithms take iterators, you have plenty of flexibility here.

Here's my variant.

I'm sticking with `std::find` because `std::any_of` adds complexity without adding clarity.

```
std::vector<char> a{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', /*...*/};

assert(a.size() >= 2);
const auto start  = a.cbegin();
const auto end    = a.cbegin() + 2;

const char search = 'b';

if (auto it = std::find(start, end, search); it != end)
{
   std::cout << "Found '" << search << "'!\n";
}
```

*([Here's more on the new `if` construction](https://skebanga.github.io/if-with-initializer/); fall back on old-school syntax if you're pre-C++17.)*

Comment: Is there some problem?