# C++ How do I check if an object is in an array?

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and I'm making my first project with it. I have an array with some strings in it and I need my code to check if an input is in that array, store it and continue with the code but I don't know how.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int battleCapacity;
string T1P1;
string pokemonlist[] = {"Bulbasaur", "Charmander", "Squirtle", "Pikachu"};

int main() {
    cout << "Pokemon Battle Buddy\nHP and Damage Calculator\nBattle Capacity: ";
    cin >> battleCapacity;
    if (battleCapacity <= 6) {
        cout << "Trainer 1; Pokemon 1: ";
        cin >> T1P1;
    } else {
        cout << "Not Working";
    }
}
```

I know in Python it is

```
if x in y:
    return
```

I'm looking for something similar to this. Thanks

Comment: [How to find out if an item is present in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/571394/9716597)  Just change `vec.begin()` to `std::begin(array)` and `vec.end()` to `std::end(array)` for arrays.

Comment: Note If you just want to know if something is in an array, and the array is reasonably large, don't use an array. Use a set.

Comment: Instead of using an array, you can use an std::vector for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to add something to the array it is much more prefarable to use vector instead of a regular array, as are of a fixed size.

that said, here is a simple function to find a string in the vector:

```
bool stringInVector(vector<string> list, string str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(list[i] == str)return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could also use the already existing function `find` as other users had already mentioned.

Here is what the complete code would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int battleCapacity;
string T1P1;
vector<string> pokemonlist= {"Bulbasaur", "Charmander", "Squirtle", "Pikachu"};

bool stringInVector(vector<string> list, string str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(list[i] == str)return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Pokemon Battle Buddy\nHP and Damage Calculator\nBattle Capacity: ";
    cin >> battleCapacity;
    if (battleCapacity <= 6) {
        cout << "Trainer 1; Pokemon 1: ";
        cin >> T1P1;
        if(stringInVector(pokemonlist, T1P1)) cout << "Exists";
    } else {
        cout << "Not Working";
    }
}
```

Comment: this gets the error ```in C++98 'pokemonlist' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'```

Comment: Change line 8 into
`vector<string> pokemonlist{"Bulbasaur", "Charmander", "Squirtle", "Pikachu"};`
instead; That should do it in C++98

Comment: Instead of the assignment we use a constructor here to initialize the vector

Comment: I've just changed my version in my ide to c++11 and now this works.

Answer (score 2):

> C++ How do I check if an object is in an array?

This can be done with the following algorithm:

```
for each element in array
    if element is the one we are searching, then
       return true
return false
```

This is called a linear search. More general version of this algorithm can iterate over any range and returns iterator to the found element. There is no need to implement this because the standard library has got it covered already: `std::find`.

Comment: how would i get ```for each element in array``` to search the whole array? Do I have to do  ```for x and y and z in array``` or something else?

Comment: @JaydenCollis You can use a loop.

Comment: can you edit to show that? I dont want to get anything wrong. Being new to c++ ive no clue what the correct syntax is for nests and loops

Comment: @JaydenCollis: it sounds like you need a good C++ book. The basic syntax here is usually `for(const auto& item : collection) { /*doStuff*/ }`

Comment: @JaydenCollis I think you've started to learn the language in the wrong way. Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2079303

Answer (score 0):

> I have an array with some strings in it and I need my code to check if an input is in that array

Instead of array you can use `vector`, then you can use `find` standard algorithm:

```
std::vector<std::string> pokemonlist = {"Bulbasaur", "Charmander", "Squirtle", "Pikachu"};

if(pokemonlist.end() != std::find(pokemonlist.begin(), pokemonlist.end(), "Charmander"))
{
    std::cout << "found Charmander\n";
}
else
{
    // not found
}
```

Comment: This creates the error ```'vector' does not name a type```

Comment: @JaydenCollis you probably need the `std::` for standard namespace. Updated, you may want to retest.

Comment: now i get ```'vector' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type```

Comment: `#include <vector>`

Comment: ```in C++98 'pokemonlist' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an already implemented function like in Python, eerorika's answer will suffice. However, if you want to understand this process, in the case of an unordered array you would visit each element in the array and if you reach the end without finding it, then it isn't there.

```
string value = "example";
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
  if (arr[i] == value)
    cout << value << " is in the array.\n";
```